# Sub menu pages not showing on admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a plugin which creates a menu page that contain 2 sub menus:

```
function create_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Main Page', 'Main Page', 'manage_options', 'main-page', 'main_page_function');

    add_submenu_page('main-page', 'First Child', 'First Child', 'manage_options', 'first-page', 'first_child_function');

    add_submenu_page('main-page', 'Second Child', 'Second Child', 'manage_options', 'second-page', 'second_child_function');
}

// Actions
add_action('admin_menu', 'create_menu');
```

On the dashboard I see the main page name "Main Page", When I hover over it or click on it, the other 2 sub menus are not shown.

Why is that?

Comment: Your code is correct and the sub menu pages show up correctly on my side.

It seems to me like there may be a JS error on your page. When you hover over the "Settings" menu item in the admin section does it show the default sub menu pages for the settings area?

Comment: @NickDuncan, Yes the code is correct and it's working now, Thanks

Comment: It works fine. double check

Comment: Great to hear. What was the issue?

Comment: @NickDuncan, A typo error in the main page slug